# Intersection of two lists with duplicate elements

Tags: prolog

I am working on defining an `intersection` predicate, that takes in two lists, allowing duplicated elements. This is what I have so far.

```
intersection([], _, []).
intersection([H1|T1], L2, [H1|R]) :- m_member(H1, L2), intersection(T1, L2, R).
intersection([_|T1], L2, R) :- intersection(T1, L2, R).
```

However, in the case of the follows:

`intersection([a,b,b,a],[c,b,b,c,e,f], S).`

The predicate-call returns `[b, b]`. I would like to return `[b]` instead. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to obtain the intersection `D` of `[X|A]` and `B` is:

- Suppose, as induction hypothesis, that the intersection of `A` and `B` is `C` (without repetition).
- Therefore:

  - if `X` is member of `C` or `X` is not member of `B`, then `D` is equal to `C`;
  - otherwise, `D` is equal to `[X|C]`.

```
% inter(++Set1, ++Set2, -Set3)

  inter([], _, []).
  inter([X|A], B, D) :-
     inter(A, B, C),
     (   (   memberchk(X, C)
         ;   \+ memberchk(X, B) )
     ->  D = C
     ;   D = [X|C]   ).
```

Example:

```
?- inter([a,b,b,a], [c,b,b,c,e,f], S).
S = [b].
```

Comment: `inter([A],[b],[]).` fails, yet its specialization `A=a, inter([A],[b],[]).` succeeds. So what exactly do you mean by `+`.

Comment: @false Actually I meant ```++```, a mode indicator for which the query ```inter([A],[b],[])``` does not make sense (see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc). Thanks for pointing out this little detail.